# Eloquent attaching a many to many results in Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: rest, api, eloquent, lumen

In my Lumen project I use a many to many relationship like this:

```
class Item{
    protected $appends = ['order'];

    public getOrderAttribute(){
      return $this->pivot->order;
    }
    public function collections(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Collection)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('order');
    }
}
```

and then in the collection

```
class Collection{
    public function items(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Item)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('order')';
    }
}
```

then I try to insert a new item in a collection like this:

```
addItem(Request $req, $id){ <- is for collection
 $item = new Item();
 $item->save();

 $collection = Collection::findOrFail($id);
 $collection->items()->attach($item, ['order' => $req->input('order')]);
return $item;
```

this result in `Trying to get property of non-object`

The data gets stored in the database succesfully and correctly.
I have tried switching up the attach on collections() and on items() but that doenst change anything.
I have tried to renew the item value like this: `Item::findOrFail($item->id)`
still results in the same error.
Abd when I refresh the page I get the correct data.

Comment: If anyone has the same problem in the future

`return $collection->items()->where('item_id', $item->id)->first();`
fixed it for me